# different colors for different routes on google maps importing multiple KML files build in google engine?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am loading multiple KML layers files into google maps. However it becomes difficult to read since they are different Bus routes on the map. Is it possible to have them in different colors for example kml1 file to be in red , kml2 file to be in blue etc. I used google engine to build these KML files however i did not get an option to use different colors on the line/markers.

```
function initialize() {
  var abby = new google.maps.LatLng(49.051078,-122.314221);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: abby
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/143598220/1.%20Blueridge-McKee%20GoLine.kml'
  });

  var ctaLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/143598220/2.%20Bluejay-Huntingdon%20GoLine.kml'
  });

var ctaLayer3 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url:'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/143598220/3.%20Clearbrook%20-%20UFV%20GoLine.kml'
  });

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
  ctaLayer2.setMap(map);
  ctaLayer3.setMap(map);

  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        disableAutoPan: true
      });



  marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:pos,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        disableAutoPan: true

  });


marker.setMap(map);

var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"Your Current Location!"
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow2.open(map,marker);
  });

   //   map.setCenter(pos);

    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };



  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);


}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The [KML spec](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) supports different colored polylines. [LineStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestyle)

Comment: Looks like they are different colors to me: [fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/aSDR5/1/)

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for the doc links those really helped me.